# How to map hash keys to methods for an encapsulated Ruby class (tableless model)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, hash

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am tryng to map a hash (`key`, `value` pairs) to an encapsulated Ruby class (tableless model) making the hash `key` as a class method that returns the `value`.

In the model file I have

```
class Users::Account #< ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize(attributes = {})
    @id        = attributes[:id]
    @firstname = attributes[:firstname]
    @lastname  = attributes[:lastname]
  end
end

def self.to_model(account)
  JSON.parse(account)
end
```

My hash is

```
hash = {\"id\":2,\"firstname\":\"Name_test\",\"lastname\":\"Surname_test\"}
```

I can make

```
account = Users::Account.to_model(hash)
```

that returns (debugging)

```
--- 
id: 2
firstname: Name_test
lastname: Surname_test
```

That works, but if I do

```
account.id
```

I get this error

```
NoMethodError in Users/accountsController#new    
undefined method `id' for #<Hash:0x00000104cda410>
```

I think because `<Hash:0x00000104cda410>` is an hash (!) and not the class itself. Also I think that doing `account = Users::Account.to_model(hash)` is not the right approach.

**What is wrong? How can I "map" those hash keys to class methods?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initailized the class with the hash. You should do:

```
json = "{\"id\":2,\"firstname\":\"Name_test\",\"lastname\":\"Surname_test\"}"
hash = Users::Account.to_model(json)
account = Users::Account.new(hash)
```

Then `account.id` will give the value.

Answer (score 1):

It would look better if you were to rewrite it like this

```
account = Users::Account.from_json(json)
```

and down there

```
def self.from_json(json_str)
   new(JSON.parse(json_str))
end
```

There is also a "block initializer" that I often use for initializing from a hash
https://github.com/guerilla-di/tracksperanto/blob/master/lib/tracksperanto/block_init.rb
so if you were to use that you could transform your class definition to

```
class Users::Account
  include BlockInit
  attr_accessor :id, :firstname, :lastname
  def self.from_json(json_str)
    new(JSON.parse(json_str))
  end
end
```